# Angular watch if condition is calling twice and thrice

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, watch

I am using watch concept to know the status change happening in another controller and doing the respetive changes in the second controller , communication between the controller is throuogh watch .If status is equal to new then the angular model popup will open with create and cancel option .

But here the if condition is calling multiple times even though the status is changing at once .And i am getting Maximum call stack size exceeded error and the whole page is hanging .

```
 $rootScope.$watch('reportStatus', function( status )
    {
      if(status == 'new'){ 
           var modalView = $modal({template: 'app/dashboard/report/createNewReport.tpl.html', persist: true, show: false, backdrop: 'static', scope: $scope});
           $q.when(modalView).then(function(modalEl) {
           modalEl.modal('show');
           });
          }
});
```

Its happening when i am going to another page and come back to click on new .

Please suggest

Comment: What are you doing inside `getIndividualReportData`?

Comment: `$watch` will be sensitive to any change made on `reportStatus`.  So, if you are changing the value of `reportStatus` inside the watch, it could loop infinitely.

Comment: @KhanhTO i am calling another function to load the individual data , but i am facing issue only with the new ,its happening when user click on on new button

Comment: @DavinTryon  : Yea that is a good point , thanks ,let me try

Comment: i have removed other condition still the first if condition is loading infinite  , I edited the question

Comment: Can you show your `createNewReport.tpl.html` and your $scope? Maybe something infinite here when the binding occurs